# Can a Python function remember its previous outputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Is there a way that a function can remember its previous output and use that value during the next call to the function? For instance, assume there is a function, `runningTotal` with a single argument `x` that returns `x` on the first call to `runningTotal` but `x + prevOutput` for every call after that.  Is there a way to write such a function in python?

I am aware that this could be easily achieved by using a global variable in the function or by saving the previous value to a new variable, but I would like to avoid these solutions if possible.  The reason I'm looking for an alternate solution is because this is one function in a program I'm working on with other people and I would like to avoid having to create more global variables than already established.

Comment: Yes: [generators](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/)

Comment: Technically speaking, generators are more than simply remembering the previous output. They keep the whole function state; so you will have access to the values of all local variables on subsequent calls.

Comment: This is a very vague question, please be more specific, [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can use a function closures. See [Simulate static variables in python with closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8175323/4996248).

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279561/4996248) contains other ways (beyond closures) to simulate static variables (variables attached to a function which keep their state between function calls).

Comment: [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) might help.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but to avoid too much hackery or GLOBAL variables we'll probably want to use a class.
In python a class can be treated as function with a magic function (method) inside the class named `__call__`.

Your question might be better written: *what's the best way to have a function in python that has internal state?*

Let's say we have the runningTotal function defined using a global variable as:

```py
TOTAL = 0
def runningTotal(inc):
    global TOTAL
    TOTAL += inc
    return TOTAL
```

**Answer** Ok so lets define a class that will behave the same way as the above function but without a global variable:

```
class StatefulFunction:
    running_total = 0

    def __call__(self, inc):
        self.running_total += inc
        return self.running_total


# create the stateful function variable
runningTotal = StatefulFunction()

# Use the stateful function
runningTotal(1)
# outputs: 1
runningTotal(5)
# outputs: 6
```

Another way to accomplish the same thing is with a *Counter Dictionary*

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter()
counter['runningTotal'] += 1
# in another part of the program
counter['runningTotal'] += 5
```

The output will be:

```
print(counter)
Counter({'runningTotal': 6})
```

Comment: This is not a good use case for a Counter

Comment: Can you elaborate why?

Answer (score 2):

Although there are ways of doing what you ask, it's not a good idea. As @JohnColeman pointed out, [Simulate static variables in python with closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175323/simulate-static-variables-in-python-with-closures)

But why not create a class?

```
class Accumulator:
    total = 0

    @classmethod
    def add(cls, x):
        cls.total += x
        return cls.total


print(Accumulator.add(1))
print(Accumulator.add(2))
print(Accumulator.add(3))
```

Result:

```
1
3
6
```

You can set up a generator to maintain state and send values to it as well, as suggested by @HeapOverflow:

```
def get_running_total():
    def _running_total():
        value = 0
        while True:
            value += yield value
    # get a generator instance
    generator = _running_total()
    # set it up to wait for input
    next(generator)
    # return the send method on the generator
    return generator.send


# you can get a generator that functions similar to the Accumulator method
running_total = get_running_total()
print(running_total(1))   # prints 1
print(running_total(2))   # prints 3
print(running_total(3))   # prints 6
```

Comment: You're right - my remark is too sharp, although I think that solution is still a bit hacky, it certainly is closer to what OP asked. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Actually made another update, you can encapsulate the setup in the function and I feel this is a cleaner solution (and reusable).

Comment: I think I had such a version as well, but dismissed it as inferior to the more normal [this](https://repl.it/repls/BraveForkedMethods). I'd say I mostly wrote a generator solution to practice it (especially the sending) and because you said it doesn't work :-P