# Is there a way to avoid revisiting/keep track of visited nodes in recursive traversal without class attribute or passed parameter?

Tags: python, graph, graph-traversal

Is there a way to do a graph based depth first traversal recursively without passing a "visited" parameter set of visited nodes (or having one as a class attribute or global variable)?

The pseudo code on wikipedia seems to indicate it is necessary.

My code (below) works after I added the default parameter to the signature given me. I didn't want to mess with the function signature at all because it's being called inside a unit test. However, a default parameter proved to be both useful and harmles, but is this the only way I could have done it, assuming I had to use recursion?

```
    def dft_recursive(self, starting_vertex, visited = set()):
        """
        Print each vertex in depth-first order
        beginning from starting_vertex.

        This should be done using recursion.
        """
        print(starting_vertex)
        visited.add(starting_vertex)
        for neighbor in self.vertices[starting_vertex]:
            if neighbor not in visited:
                visited.add(neighbor)
                self.dft_recursive(neighbor, visited)
```

Comment: Well it's the whole function. It's part of a larger class but it works as is. My question is more theoretical and it should be clear what's going on (an adjacency list of self.vertices is the graph)

Comment: is this the whole code? Also may you add what's the input in this test Algo?  Also I may miss the point of why you are asking this? i think that you should marked node as visited and in a depth first traversal should be the most logical thing to do. So maybe if you specify why you have this doubt is more understandable

Comment: yes ok, even if is theoretical, unless other users have a straight answer there may be a bit of testing to see if is possible to achieve this

Comment: I assumed this would be a well trodden path that people would already know the answer to. Boiling is down, does each individual function call need an outside record of nodes visited or can you make the calls in a way that doesn't infinitely run or at least over-run. Now that I verbalize it, I think not.

Comment: I think I know the answer now. You need a list of visited nodes and the passing of a default parameter was the slickest way to do it. I'm just trying to get really good at graph algorithms.

Comment: Your example code will only work right *once* per run of your program.  Calling the function again will reuse the same `visited` set as before, rather than starting with an empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to demonstrate this let's consider the following [undirected graphs](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/graphs-directed-vs-undirected-graph#undirected-graphs) Graph:

[image]

### 1. Using Node Class instance

Implementing a Node's Class which which stores the Visited boolean Flag status itself.
Also note as se store the `neighbours` within the Node's Class itself.

```py
class Node:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.neighbours = []
        self.visited = False
        self.previous_node = None # NOTE: This is just to show the printed result not really needed

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} can go to = {self.neighbours}, is Visited? = {self.visited}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    def add_path(self, node_to):
        if isinstance(node_to, Node):
            if node_to not in self.neighbours:
                self.neighbours.append(node_to)
            else:
                print(f'Error, added node_to is already a neighbour of {self.name}')
        else:
            print(f'Error adding the new Node neighbour, it must be a instance of Node')

    def has_unvisited_neighbour(self):  
        """Check the Node's neighbours, return False if even one node is False hence not visited"""
        check_neighbours = [node.visited for node in self.neighbours]
        return all(check_neighbours)


class Graph:

    def __init__(self, nodes: list):
        self.nodes = {node: Node(node) for node in nodes}

    def create_graph(self, paths: list):
        node_from, nodes_to = paths
        if node_from in self.nodes:
            get_node_from = self.nodes.get(node_from)
            for node in nodes_to:
                get_node_to = self.nodes.get(node)
                self.nodes[node_from].add_path(get_node_to)
                self.nodes[node].add_path(get_node_from)
        else:
           print('Error while creating Graph, an unknown node was entered :(')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Graph({self.nodes})'

    def show_nodes(self):
        for node in self.nodes.values():
            print(node)

    def dft_recursive(self, starting_vertex):    
        starting_vertex = self.nodes[starting_vertex]
        starting_vertex.visited = True
        for neighbor in starting_vertex.neighbours:
            if not neighbor.visited:
                neighbor.visited = True
                neighbor.previous_node = starting_vertex # NOTE: This is just to show the printed result not really needed
                if not neighbor.has_unvisited_neighbour():  # If False means we reached a dead end
                    print(starting_vertex.name, end=' --> ')
                    self.dft_recursive(neighbor.name)
                else: 
                    print(neighbor.previous_node.name, '--> ', neighbor.name, '| ')
                    continue

nodes_list = ['Earth', 'Moon', 'Mars', 'Venus',
              'Mercury', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn',
              'Neptune', 'Uranus', 'Sun', 'Comet', 'Blackhole']

path_earth = ['Earth', ('Moon', 'Mars', 'Venus')]
path_venus = ['Venus', ('Blackhole',)]
path_mercury = ['Mercury', ('Sun', 'Mars', 'Comet')]
path_mars = ['Mars', ('Jupiter', )]
path_jupiter = ['Jupiter', ('Saturn',)]
path_saturn = ['Saturn', ('Neptune',)]
path_neptune = ['Neptune', ('Uranus',)]
paths = [path_earth, path_venus, path_mercury, path_mars, path_jupiter, path_saturn, path_neptune]

# ----- Creating the Graph
my_graph = Graph(nodes_list)
for path in paths:
    my_graph.create_graph(path)
my_graph.dft_recursive('Earth')
```

---

### 2. Using A StateFul Closure

Python has first-class functions, meaning you can assign them to variables, pass them as
arguments to other functions, compare them in expressions, etc.

A **Closure** is a function object that remembers values in enclosing scopes even if they are not present in memory, you can see it be implemented in the `stateful_closure` function.

```py
class Graph:

    def __init__(self, nodes: list):
        self.nodes = {node: [] for node in nodes}

    def create_graph(self, paths: list):
        node_from, nodes_to = paths
        if node_from in self.nodes:
            for node in nodes_to:
                self.nodes[node_from].append(node)
                self.nodes[node].append(node_from)
        else:
           print('Error while creating Graph, an unknown node was entered :(')


    def dft_recursive(self, starting_vertex):
        """Depth First Search using a stateful closure to keep track of Visited Node"""

        visited_nodes = set()

        def stateful_closure(starting_vertex):
            """Recursive stateful Closure function"""

            visited_nodes.add(starting_vertex)  # FAQ: This is a Closure
            starting_vertex_name = starting_vertex
            starting_vertex = self.nodes[starting_vertex]

            for neighbor in starting_vertex:
                if neighbor not in visited_nodes:
                    visited_nodes.add(neighbor)

                    if not all([bool(node in visited_nodes) for node in self.nodes[neighbor]]):
                        print(starting_vertex_name, end=' --> ')
                        stateful_closure(neighbor)
                    else:
                        print(starting_vertex_name, '--> ', neighbor, '| ')
                        continue

        stateful_closure(starting_vertex)    

# Same as prev function, shorted form to save space
nodes_list = ['Earth', 'Moon', 'Mars', 'Venus',
              'Mercury', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn',
              'Neptune', 'Uranus', 'Sun', 'Comet', 'Blackhole']
paths = [['Earth', ('Moon', 'Mars', 'Venus')],  ['Venus', ('Blackhole',)],  ['Mercury', ('Sun', 'Mars', 'Comet')],
         ['Mars', ('Jupiter', )], ['Jupiter', ('Saturn',)], ['Saturn', ('Neptune',)], ['Neptune', ('Uranus',)]]

# ----- Creating the Graph
my_graph = Graph(nodes_list)
for path in paths:
    my_graph.create_graph(path)

my_graph.dft_recursive('Earth')
```

---

### Documentation | Guides | Other StackOverflow answers

- [Can a Python function remember its previous outputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674321/can-a-python-function-remember-its-previous-outputs)
- [Closures](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Closures)