# Reframe pipeline function with a generator

Tags: python, generator

I have a `pipeline` function that takes an arbitrary number of functions as arguments, it returns a single function `helper` which contain one argument and this function in turn calls the `pipeline` function with a single argument iteratively. Here is the code:

```
def pipeline(*funcs):
    def helper(arg):
        for func in funcs:
            result = func(arg)
            arg = result
        return result
    return helper
```

And here a test case:

```
fun = pipeline(lambda x: x * 3, lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x / 2)
print(fun(3)) #should print 5.0
```

I was reading on a different question about generators and how they can be used to remember previous state [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59674321/can-a-python-function-remember-its-previous-outputs), and was wondering if I could reframe my current `pipeline` function to use a generator instead. I need to remember the `arg` for every `func` call and currently I'm doing that by storing into a variable, however since generators can remember the last state I was wondering if I could use it instead.

Comment: it returns `5.0`... what do you mean by `[...]#should print 5.0`?

Answer (score 1):

You could (but absolutely shouldn't) create a side-effect based list-comprehension that uses the walrus-operator:

```
funcs = [lambda x: x * 3, lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x / 2]

x = 3
[x := f(x) for f in funcs]
print(x)
```

What makes this even worse than it already is is the fact that if you use a simple generator instead of the list-comprehension the result is different because it doesn't all get executed before the print.

Or you even force it all in one line like this:

```
print([x := f(x if i>0 else 3) for i, f in enumerate(funcs)][-1])
```

I think generally a prettier approach would be to just wrap it into a normal for loop:

```
x = 3
for f in funcs:
    x = f(x)
print(x)
```

Comment: What do you mean by  _"side-effect based list-comprehension"_?

Comment: I mean using a list comprehension only for the effect is has on the variables inside it instead of its return value (e.g. `[print(i) for i in range(5)]`) which to my knowledge is bad style and should be avoided.